# xenbr1 dissappeared after server reboot

Tags: xen, linux-networking

I'm running a Xen 3.0 server and after rebooting it, the xenbr1 networking bridge never came back.  Both eth0 and eth1 are running fine and all the IP addresses are present, however it looks like it did not start the virtual networking.

On this server:

```
brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
virbr0      8000.000000000000   yes
```

On an identical server that is working:

```
 brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
virbr0      8000.000000000000   yes     
xenbr1      8000.feffffffffff   no      peth1
                            vif0.1
```

When I try to add the xenbr1 using:

```
/etc/xen/scripts/network-bridge netdev=eth1 bridge=xenbr1 start
```

I get the error

```
/etc/xen/scripts/network-bridge netdev=eth1 bridge=xenbr1 start

Link veth1
1 is missing.
This may be because you have reached the limit of the number of interfaces
that the loopback driver supports.  If the loopback driver is a module, you
may raise this limit by passing it as a parameter (nloopbacks=); if the
driver is compiled statically into the kernel, then you may set the parameter
using loopback.nloopbacks= on the domain 0 kernel command line.
```

Any suggestions? The only thing I know of that was added to this server since the last reboot was tgtd, but this is running on other servers and they come up correctly after reboots.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is probably accurate, but there is a better way to do networking. It is recommended to do bridging manually and has even become the default for Xen 4.1+.

You can set up the networking bridges manually on *any* version of Xen by following:

http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/HostConfiguration/Networking

The basic idea (which is different than what you are used to) is that the xenbrN device gets the IP address and the ethN device is used only as a port for the xenbrN device to communicate over.

By following the instructions above you should then disable the bridge scripts in the xend configuration file (/etc/xen/xend-config.sxp).

```
# (network-script network-bridge)
# (vif-script vif-bridge)
```